# bsoncxx::to_json return corrupted string

Tags: c++, json, c++11, bson, mongo-cxx-driver

I'm having difficulties converting a bson document to a json string using bsoncxx.
The bsoncxx::to_json function return an "invalid"/corrupted std::string object..
I can't read the character in it, and it crash when the std::string is destructed..

I've rebuild everything: mongoc,libbson, mongocxx, etc...

Here's a sample code :

```
bsoncxx::builder::basic::document doc{};
doc.append(bsoncxx::builder::basic::kvp("test", 1));
auto string = bsoncxx::to_json(doc);
```

I can't extract the data from the string, because std::end(string) crash with a "read access violation" when I try to copy the content with std::copy...

[image]

I'm using mongodb everywhere in the program and accessing bson documents and everything works fine. I tried to call bsoncxx::to_json on an already existing bson document returned by a mongodb query but it had the same behavior...

I'm trying to stream a byte array ( plus, some information like how to decode the byte array ) using boost tcp sockets to a nodejs program so I thought I could simply create a document with a "binary field", convert it to json and stream it over the tcp socket...

Anyone knows how I could do that, either by fixing the bsoncxx::to_json, or by using something else ?

thanks

Edit:

For information, I'm compiling with Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10 x64

Comment: Hi, could you please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?  I'd like to try it on Windows and Linux and see if I can replicate it.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay. Do you need a zip with the .dll and and everthing or only the main cpp file ? Because I did a new project with only the 3 line in the question ( + the includes ) and It have the same behavior

Comment: https://1drv.ms/f/s!AueTJubu1l2CgzPHROVvdil6yOau

Here's a link with everything except boost. I'm using boost 1.61

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem by using libbson directly, instead of bsoncxx... I took at look a the code in bsoncxx::to_json, and extracted that :

```
std::string ret;

bson_t bson;
auto view = document.view();
bson_init_static(&bson, view.data(), view.length());

size_t size;
auto result = bson_as_json(&bson, &size);
if (!result)
    return "Error converting to json";

ret = std::string(result);

bson_free(result);

return std::move(ret);
```

Seems to work fine!

Comment: Just wanted to thank you for this snipped above. I keep on getting errors with bsoncxx::to_json, but your code worker like dream!!! Thank you so much!